# What is Android's google app theme?

Tags: android, android-theme, look-and-feel

I am building an Android app and need to make it look like Android's stock google app (the one with the "G" icon) or google maps app. What theme are these google apps using?

The TripAdvisor app, for instance, has a very similar look and feel as the default google app. Is it possible to achieve the same look and feel like the stock google apps?

Would someone please let me know? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referring to "Material Design".

Its a design language which google rolled out on Android in 2015.

It aims to streamline the UI and provide a consistent experience across all user experiences on a device, so apps fee native.

More details at:

https://material.io/guidelines

https://design.google.com/resources/